# Create Custom Calendar view with viewpager

Tags: android, calendar

How to create the Calendar view like this
[image]

on days section is swipeable and on clicks of arrows week should get change. Is there any library available for this?

Comment: You can use normal grid view and using calender class you can load the dates.On click of next button you need to load next week's dates from calender.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and seems the best:
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Check this links too,

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27

https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2715